# Save, Export & Import the Preferences & Customized Interface (Toolbars Editor) configuration/ settings of VLC Player

Tags: vlc-media-player

Save, Export & Import the Preferences & Customized Interface (Toolbars Editor) configuration/ settings of VLC Player - VLC 2.2.6 Umbrella (latest).  I'd especially like to "maintain" my Toolbars/ Buttons/ Spacing that I set up (will update with pics once on Windows)

Comment: [Where does VLC store its config file?](https://www.videolan.org/support/faq.html#Config).

Comment: @DavidPostill - If I only knew, I'd have half the answer on how to go about this

Answer (score 1):

As per VLC website suggested by comment link above we found the general direction of the Config/ Settings for VLC.

But, it seems the path is a bit inaccurate for Windows 7/8.x/10 versions.

It's actually in this location, and probably these 2 files.

```
C:\Users\%UserName%\AppData\Roaming\vlc

..\vlc-qt-interface  
..\vlcrc
```

Now upon changing settings/ preferences we noticed as per Last Modified time stamp that these 2 files are probably it. But, we are not sure about this due to lack of official documentation from VLC on this.

PS: This answer is subject update as we find more on this front.